# Reactor Netty not getting an HttpServer response when the HttpClient subscribes, only when HttpClient blocks

Tags: java, netty, reactive-programming, reactor-netty

Using the sample HttpClient/HttpServer examples in github, I am trying to print a response from the sample HttpServer when the HttpClient subscribes rather than blocks. Here is the sample HttpServer used:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()
                        .host("10.0.0.19")
                        .port(61005)
                        .route(routes ->
                                routes.get("/hello",
                                        (request, response) -> response.sendString(Mono.just("Hello World!")))
                                    .post("/echo",
                                        (request, response) -> response.sendString(Mono.just("Hello World!"))))
                        .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
                .block();
    }
}
```

Here are the maven dependencies used by the HttpClient and HttpServer:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

If the HttpClient blocks, the request and response work correctly as in this blocking code:

```
public class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String responseStr = HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.host("10.0.0.19"))
                .port(61005)
                .post()
                .uri("/echo")
                .send(ByteBufFlux.fromString(Mono.just("Hello")))
                .responseContent()
                .aggregate()
                .asString()
                .block();

        System.out.println(responseStr);
    }
}
```

But is the HttpClient subcribes with onSuccess, onError and onCompletion callbacks, there is no response, that is, neither onSuccess, onError or onCompletion are executed:

```
public class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Consumer<String> onSuccess = (String response) -> {
            log.info("response in onSuccess: "+response);

        };
        Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
            ex.getMessage();
        };

        Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
            System.out.println("Message Completed");

        };

            HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.host("10.0.0.19"))
                .port(61005)
                .post()
                .uri("/echo")
                .send(ByteBufFlux.fromString(Mono.just("Hello")))
                .responseContent()
                .aggregate()
                .asString()
                .subscribe(onSuccess, onError, onCompletion);
    }
}
```

I have not been able to find an example that uses subscribe(). In the above example of the HttpClient using subscribe(), the HttpServer does not appear to be returning a response. Any incite into why this appears to be happening would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In Reactor Netty examples, `.block` is used in order to keep the `main` thread active as we do not want the thread to exit.
When you use `.subscribe` you need another mechanism for keeping the `main` thread active and prevent it from exiting.
What happens in your example is that the `main` thread exits and you cannot see the results.

You can use for example `CountDownLatch`

```
public class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        Consumer<String> onSuccess = (String response) -> {
            log.info("response in onSuccess: "+response);

        };
        Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
            ex.getMessage();
            latch.countDown();
        };

        Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
            System.out.println("Message Completed");
            latch.countDown();
        };

            HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.host("10.0.0.19"))
                .port(61005)
                .post()
                .uri("/echo")
                .send(ByteBufFlux.fromString(Mono.just("Hello")))
                .responseContent()
                .aggregate()
                .asString()
                .subscribe(onSuccess, onError, onCompletion);

            latch.await();
    }
}
```